# Show HTML and PHP code in one line

Tags: php, html

I want to show this sentence:

```
?>
<h2>Date <?php echo "$day"."/"."$month"."/"."$year"."<br>"; ?></h2>
<?php
```

I have tried:

```
echo '<h2>Date '$day'.'/'.'$month'.'/'.'$year'.'<br>' </h2>';
echo '<h2>Date <?php echo \"$day/\".\"/\".\"$month\".\"/\".\"$year\".\"<br>\"; ?></h2>';
```

Without success.

If a line contains both HTML and PHP code, what is the proper format to display it?

Comment: Do you want to showcase the output as PHP code completely or just want to print date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nicest way to do this is probably with [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), which substitutes variables into your string according to placeholders:

```
printf('<h2>Date %s/%s/%s<br></h2>', $day, $month, $year);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `%d` is an integer. This means you will lose any leading 0s if you had any. `%s` is probably better.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen That's a good point. Fingers ahead of brain! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

You have a "dot mess".

You can concatinate PHP variables and strings like

```
<?pho echo 'string' . $var . 'string' . $var1 . $var2; // and so on ?>
```

So correct solutions would be

```
<?php

echo '<h2>Date ' . $day . '/'. $month .'/' . $year .'<br></h2>';
echo '<h2>Date ' , $day , '/', $month ,'/', $year ,'<br></h2>';

echo "<h2>Date $day/$month/$year<br></h2>";
echo "<h2>Date {$day}/{$month}/{$year}<br></h2>";

?>
```

You can even use commas `,` for echoing strings and variables that's a bit faster. Cause PHP does not concatinate all parts together to a single string and echos it but echos every part separatly (so less operations are needed).

Note that if you put a string in double quotes `"` you can use `$var` or `{$var}` inside the string cause PHP is looking vor PHP variables inside a double quoted string and replaces them by their containing value.

**But the fastest solution is the `,` separated version.**

**or**

As [lonesomeday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417562/lonesomeday) mentioned there is also a `C` like solution possible in PHP

```
<?php printf('<h2>Date %s/%s/%s<br></h2>', $day, $month, $year); ?>
```

**or (but not recommended by me)**

The complicated and none readable version

```
<h2>Date <?php echo $day; ?> / <?php echo  $month; ?> / <?php echo $year; ?><br></h2>
```

And the shorted version of the above code (just for completeness, short tags have to be enabled in PHP versions lower than 5.4 to work)

```
<h2>Date <?= $day; ?> / <?=  $month; ?> / <?= $year; ?><br></h2>
```

For even more information about string concatination read the offical PHP doc site about [String Operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: My code was a mess indeed, thank you for showing the appropriate format. Much easier to read too!

Comment: Using the echo tag version would be better in the last case: `<h2>Date <?= $day ?>/<?= $month ?>/<?= $year ?><br></h2>` Not great, though, I agree.

Comment: `<?=` can be used even when short tags are not enabled [from PHP 5.4 onwards](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), FWIW.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thx for poining me to this. Fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
?>
<h2>Date <?php echo $day."/".$month."/".$year."<br>"; ?></h2>
<?php
```

You don't need quotes when using variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo '<h2>Date ' . $day . '/'. $month .'/' . $year .'</h2>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
This will display the code as it is in your browser

```
<?php

echo htmlspecialchars('<h2>Date <?php echo \"$day/\".\"/\".\"$month\".\"/\".\"$year\".\"<br>\"; ?></h2>');

?>
```

O/P:

```
<h2>Date <?php echo \"$day/\".\"/\".\"$month\".\"/\".\"$year\".\"<br>\"; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
  echo "<h2>Date $day / $month / $year <br></h2>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your answer

```
<h2>Date <?php echo "\$day"."/"."\$month"."/"."\$year"."<br>"; ?></h2>
```

or

```
<?php echo '<h2>Date '.$day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year.'<br></h2>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
echo '<h2>Date '$day'.'/'.'$month'.'/'.'$year'.'<br>' </h2>';
echo '<h2>Date <?php echo \"$day\"."/".\"$month\"."/".\"$year\".\"<br>\"; ?></h2>';
```